# Economy Object Doesnt Have An Attribute ctx

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was making a economy cog but I kept on getting an error saying "Economy object doesn't have an attribute ctx"

here is my code on the command

```py
    @commands.command(name="bet", aliases=["be", "b"], brief="You bet for honeycomb", description="If you lose you give honeycomb, if you win you get honeycomb")
    async def _bet(self, ctx, amount : int = 5):
        with open("data/eco.json", "r") as dataRead:
            with open("data/eco.json", "r") as dataRead:
                cance = [True, False]
                random_chance = random.choice(cance)
                dataReadJSON = json.load(dataRead)
                if random_chance:
                    dataReadJSON[str(self.ctx.author.id)] += int(amount*2)
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Bet", description=f"You bet and won <:honeycomb0:879275123486633984>{amount*2}", color=0xffff00)
                
                elif not random_chance:
                    dataReadJSON[str(self.ctx.author.id)] -= int(amount)
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Bet", description=f"You bet and lost <:honeycomb0:879275123486633984>{amount}", color=0xff0000)

            with open("data/eco.json", "w") as dataWrite:
                json.dump(dataReadJSON, dataWrite)
            
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: error is in line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIX**

I found this fix when I was testing so to fix it you have to remove the self in every ctx ONLY USE SELF IF YOU'RE DOING CLIENT BUT NOT FOR CTX

Example :

```py
@commands.command()
async def ping(self, ctx):
     await ctx.send("Pong! {int(self.client.latency*1000)}ms.")
```